# How to convert 3D images into the point clouds?

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, point-clouds, marching-cubes

The point cloud, a set of points representing the external surface of objects, is commonly generated by 3D scanners or photogrammetry software. It alleviates the direct computational resource demands for analyzing the images. Conversely, I have a repository of grayscale 3D XCT images and wish to transform them into point clouds. For example, please see the following figure.

[image: Example]

Could you advise on the procedure to accomplish this? Are there any tools or algorithms for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so, marching cubes? you should have found that as you researched the question ([ask]). that's an algorithm from computer graphics (point clouds, voxels, triangle meshes, are all geometry, i.e. graphics). just go off and learn some computer graphics.